# scrollViewDidScroll not getting called in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiwebview

I was trying to get callback in `scrollViewDidScroll:` method when I load html string in `webView` but the content is scrolling and `scrollViewDidScroll` is not getting called. If I pass the `URLRequest` object in webView it works fine.

One thing what I noticed is that if I tried to load html string then the scrollView content size is same as scroll view size and if I try to load url it gives scrollView content size greater than scrollView size and in that case `scrollViewDidScroll:` getting call.

I have tried so many things. First I set the scroll View Delegate `webView.scrollView.delegate = self` and implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` method but it doesn't work, then I made a child class of webView which conform to scroll view delegate. I override `scrollViewDidScroll:` as

```
protocol MyWebViewDelegate: class {
    func myWebViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
}

class MyWebView: UIWebView {
    public weak var scrollViewDelegate: MyWebViewDelegate?
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        super.scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView)
        scrollViewDelegate?.myWebViewDidScroll(scrollView)
    }
}
```

Now I conform `MyWebViewDelegate` protocol and implement method `myWebViewDidScroll:`. After doing all the work I got callback in `myWebViewDidScroll:` but when scroll view bounced.

Answer (score 1):

are you set up delegate only for UIWebView.set the  delegate of scrollView.

```
webView.scrollView.delegate = self
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have set all the delegates and `scrollViewDidScroll` is getting called when webView is bounced. And as I already described if I load `URLRequest` object, it works fine with same code. I have only problem with loading html string.